# transaction log shipping sql server 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, transactions

I have a reporting setup with SSRS on our sql server 2005 database. Because sql server 2008 is not supported by the main program which populates our database we are stuck with 2005 on our prod database. Unfortunately when I run our weekly check reports the web interface constantly times out because the server cant do the conversion to PDF. I've read that sql server 2008's SSRS is ALOT better with memory management. I was wondering if I can do some kind transact log shipping subscription publication from 2005 to 2008? Am I chasing a dream here.

Currently I have to open up the ssrs project in visual studio and run the reports inside because it doesn't ever time out when doing the pdf conversion, only times out if I try to run it through the ssis web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Um, we run 2008 SSRS against SQl Server 2000 datbases all time, Why can't you do the same with the SQL Serer 2005 database as your data source? Nothing says your report SQL Server has to be the same version fo teh database as the data.

Comment: wouldn't we need an installed copy of sql server 2008 then? My companies IT budget for this year is nearly used up as we just went through a major conversion over the last 12 months. What version of sql server would be best if its going to be used just to get at the SSRS 2008 portion?

Comment: Yes you would need a report server with SQL SErver 2008 on it.